# Handling status >= 400 in streamed node.js request http client

Tags: node.js, node-request, node.js-stream

I'm making an HTTP request using https://github.com/request/request and I want to receive JSON. The response will be seriously large, so I want to use a stream approach to process the response. However, the API I'm calling returns 'text/plain' for status >= 400, which means that my JSONStream will bork. Code:

```
  req = request.get({url: data_url});
  req.pipe(require('JSONStream').parse([true]))
    .pipe(require('stream-batch')({maxItems: 1000}))
    .on('data', callback)
    .on('end', done);
```

Error:

```
Invalid JSON (Unexpected "I" at position 0 in state STOP)
```

("A" as in "Internal server error".) It seems request does not emit 'error' events for requests that completes so adding `req.on('error', (err) => ...)` does not trigger. I could add

```
req.on('response', function(res) {
  if(res.statusCode >= 400) { ... }
})
```

But then I seem not to be able to get at the error message in the body.

How can I get at the error message, log meaningfully and break processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the argument passed to the `response` event is a readable stream as well, you can create the pipeline inside its handler:

```
req.on('response', function(res) {
  if (res.statusCode >= 400) {
    let chunks = [];
    res.on('data', c => chunks.push(c))
       .on('end', () => {
         console.log('error', Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
       });
  } else {
    res.pipe(require('JSONStream').parse([true]))
       .pipe(require('stream-batch')({maxItems: 1000}))
       .on('data', callback)
       .on('end', done);
  }
})
```

Comment: Ooo, once observed, so obvious! Thx.